# Jvector change country name to database name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have used `Jvectormap` it is working well. Now its work function if I click country showing country name .

[image]
  i have created simple database particular country.  connected database via ajax its working well.its showing alert msg database created country.

[image]

created database Canada country.But now I want display database in when click Canada show details from database not in alert box? please help me?

script:

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){
      var $ = jQuery;
      $('#focus-single').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {region: 'AU', animate: true});
      });
      $('#focus-multiple').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {regions: ['AU', 'JP'], animate: true});
      });
      $('#focus-coords').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 7, lat: 35, lng: 33, animate: true});
      });
      $('#focus-init').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 1, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, animate: true});
      });
      $('#map1').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        panOnDrag: true,
        focusOn: {
          x: 0.5,
          y: 0.5,
          scale: 1,
          animate: true
        },
        series: {
          regions: [{
            scale: ['#688FA0'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            values: {

             // "TD":23.4,
             // "TH": 312.61,
              "TL": 0.62,
              // "TZ":1.56,
              "TO": 0.3,
             // "TT": 21.2,
              //"TM":21.2,
             // "TR": 729.05,
              //"TJ":21.2,
             // "TN":4.3,
             //  "YE":0.3,
             // "UA": 136.56,
              // "QA":0.72,
              "GB": 2258.57,
              // "GA":4.6,
              "US": 14624.18,
               //"UG":4.3,
              //"UY": 40.71,
              // "UZ":0.72,
              "VU": 0.72,
              // "VE":5.77,
             // "VN": 101.99,
              // "ZW":8.4,
             //  "ZM":2.5,

            }
          }]
        },
        onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
        var map = $('#map1').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
        var name = map.getRegionName(code);
      /*
    onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
    //search through data to find the selected country by it's code
    var country = $.grep(data.countries, function(obj, index) {
    return obj.code == code;
    })[0]; //snag the first one
    if (country != undefined) {
        el.html(el.html() + "<br/><b>Code: </b>" +country.code + "<br/><b>Continent : </b> " + country.continent);
    }
       */

        // get from DB using ajax

    $(document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'database.php',

    data: {country: name},
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
      //  alert(data);

    }
});
    });

},
      });
    })




  </script>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydatabase";

$_country = $_GET['country'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT countryId,country,pdogcoregion,ccl,category FROM countrydetails WHERE country='".$_country."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "country: " . $row["country"];
    }
} else {
    echo "No database";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

name display from this file i update simple part code this file

```
$.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'world_mill_en',{"insets": [{"width": 900.0, "top": 0, "height": 440.7063107441331, "bbox": [{"y": -12651089.408837218, "x": -19971805.562327016}, {"y": 6919135.471157653, "x": 19994044.625421535}], "left": 0}], "paths": {"BD": {"path": "M652.71,228.85l-0.04,1.38l-0.46,-0.21l-0.42,0.3l0.05,0.65l-0.17,-1.37l-0.48,-1.26l-1.08,-1.6l-0.23,-0.13l-2.31,-0.11l-0.31,0.36l0.21,0.98l-0.6,1.11l-0.8,-0.4l-0.37,0.09l-0.23,0.3l-0.54,-0.21l-0.78,-0.19l-0.38,-2.04l-0.83,-1.89l0.4,-1.5l-0.16,-0.35l-1.24,-0.57l0.36,-0.62l1.5,-0.95l0.02,-0.49l-1.62,-1.26l0.64,-1.31l1.7,1.0l0.12,0.04l0.96,0.11l0.19,1.62l0.25,0.26l2.38,0.37l2.32,-0.04l1.06,0.33l-0.92,1.79l-0.97,0.13l-0.23,0.16l-0.77,1.51l0.05,0.35l1.37,1.37l0.5,-0.14l0.35,-1.46l0.24,-0.0l1.24,3.92Z", "name": "Bangladesh"}, "BE": {"path": "M429.28,143.95l1.76,0.25l0.13,-0.01l2.16,-0.64l1.46,1.34l1.26,0.71l-0.23,1.8l-0.44,0.08l-0.24,0.25l-0.2,1.36l-1.8,-1.22l-0.23,-0.05l-1.14,0.23l-1.62,-1.43l-1.15,-1.31l-0.21,-0.1l-0.95,-0.04l-0.21,-0.68l1.66,-0.54Z", "name": "Belgium"}
```

Please help me anybody. I am new in jQuery and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "country: " . $row["country"];
    }
}`
You are still returning the country.
try
`if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "category: " . $row["category"];
    }
}`

Comment: i getting category approved value.but i want  to set when i click country i want to show that country name  from database its showing alert only ?ho w i will set ?

Comment: Can you show 10  lines of your database item here, including the Canada row?

Comment: '1', 'canada', 'North America', 'None', 'Giovanni Facciponte', 'Approved' 
'2', 'India', 'ROW', 'None', 'Ritika Balaji', 'Require Approvel'
'3', 'China', 'ROW', 'None', '', 'Require Approvel'
'4', 'United States of America', 'North America', 'None', 'Ben Lanning', 'Approved'

Comment: click country showing country name jvector file but i want set if click country name get from database?

Comment: Currently the "Country" field in your database is also named "canada". So if you want to use other name?

Comment: yes.i am saying  now working jvector map if i click country name getting country name in default.but i want show details from database

Comment: In your "onRegionClick" remove the '$(document ).ready(function() {'
just need the Ajax there. 
change your  '//  alert(data);'
into  'alert(data.category);'